# My jQuery working but callback is not working on the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a simple project to learn jQuery. My problem is after clicking the button, I call a jquery. It works and carries data to the controller but success function is not working at first click. It works on the second click properly. With my parameters, in these two calls, the method in controller returns true. but at first call, jquery does not running in the success function, but second call does.

Here is my jquery:

```
function signin() {
    var parameters = {
        email: $('#emailtxt').val(),
        password: $('#passwordtxt').val()
    };
    console.log(parameters);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Login","Session")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (correctData) {

            if (JSON.parse(correctData) == false) {
                alert("Incorrect e-mail or password.");
            } else if (JSON.parse(correctData) == true) {
                window.location.assign('@Url.Action("Index","Home")');
            }
        }            
    });
};
```

Here is my codes in controller:

```
public JsonResult Login(string email, string password)
        {
            using (var context= new ProjistDbContext())
            {
                var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserEmail == email && x.UserPassword == password);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(false);
                    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["UserId"] = user.Id;
                    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(true);
                    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }
```

I kindly ask for your help in this issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the ajax call made the first time (check network tab)? Is it getting the expected result (check response tab on the selected ajax call)

Comment: Also you do not really need the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(true)` call. Just pass the boolean value to the `Json` method and remove the `JSON.parse` from client side.

Comment: Thank you for your JsonConvert tip and yes, ajax made the call even in the first time.

Comment: what is returning in the first time? add error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
Then you can see why is failing the first time. What is returning.

Comment: @MaximilianoPoggio I added your code and even no alert.

Comment: Is the ajax call getting a 200 OK with the expected results ? BTW you have a script error in your code. Missing a closing quote `window.location.assign('@Url.Action("Index","Home")');`

Comment: @Shyju in my code I have the closing quote but I accidentally delete it when I posted here, I think. by the way it's getting a 200 OK.

Comment: So then it is executing the `If` block or `else` block ? Put an alert in both and verify one of those are working.

Comment: @Shyju it executes `console.log(parameters);` even in the first call, but not the alert in `if` or `else` block.

Comment: You should console.log(correctData) to see what you controller returns

Comment: Your code worked fine for me (With the missing quote fix). Check your browser console for any script errors. Also log the `correctData` before `if`

Comment: Yup, I also just tested the code and I don't see an issue outside of the unnecessary JSON conversions.

Comment: I also added `console.log(correctData);`. My missing quote also had been fixed, but in that success function, I couldn't work the codes in any way. No error, no logs in that callback.

Comment: comment out the ` window.location.assign` line and see what happens. That line does a new GET request to that page, hence you are loosing the console messages. Or enable "preserve logs" in console settings.

Comment: @Shyju I left only alerts in if-else blocks. Preserve longs enabled too. The result is same.

Comment: @Shyju after running project, before clicking the button, I refreshed the page many times. the success function doesn't work at first as usual. at the second call, it worked. I refreshed the page again and it worked at the first clicking. I'm so confused.

Comment: What browser are you using ? Try chrome incognito mode

Comment: @Shyju I am using chrome and I also tried incognito but not helped.

Comment: Like I said earlier, I copied and tried your code locally and it worked as expected for me.

Comment: @Shyju Thank you for your assistance. You tried to help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and I wanted to share it. The problem was caused because of that...
I was adding button like;

```
<button>...</button>
```

This kind of definition was refreshing page and it was causing error while getting response from controller. It also gave error sometimes like

> XHR failed loading GET...

If I add type="button" to html button definition, it stops to refresh page and all posts and responses works good.

I would like to share the solution. Thank you all for your assistance.